# What causes a method to pass null values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side

So I wrote a method of code and it pulls from the database correctly (I am using Dapper), but it doesnt pass off to the next method. Can anyone tell me why and what I am doing wrong? Not quite understanding what I am doing wrong here. I have tried a few different ways including below and making and IEnumerable list. I can see the variables in the logger so I know I am pulling them correctly, just not sure why they arent sending to the CheckSite().

```
public class UptimeService
{
    private readonly ILogger<UptimeService> _logger;
    private readonly IWebsiteData _webdb;
    private readonly IUptimeData _db;
    public UptimeService(IWebsiteData webdb, IUptimeData db ,ILogger<UptimeService> logger) 
    {

        _webdb = webdb;
        _logger = logger;
        _db= db;
    }
    public class SiteResponse
    {
        public int Websiteid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public long ResponseTime { get; set; }


    }


    public async Task GetAllWebsites()
    {
       
        var websites = await _webdb.GetWebsites();


        foreach (var website in websites)
        {
         
            _logger.LogInformation($"WEBSITE::::: {website.Url} | {website.Name} | {website.Websiteid}");
            CheckSite(website.Url, website.Name, website.Websiteid);
        }
        return ;
         
    }

    public SiteResponse CheckSite(string Url, string Name, int Websiteid)
    
    {
        var result = new SiteResponse();
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        _logger.LogInformation(
                            $"TEST URL: {result.Url}");
        try
        {
            var checkingResponse = client.GetAsync(Url).Result;
            
            result.Status = checkingResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode &&
                            checkingResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        catch
        {
            result.Status = false;
            // offline
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        result.ResponseTime = elapsed;

    
        if (result.Status)
        {
            // archive record
            RecordToDb(result);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                             $"Status is {result.Status}");
        }
        return result;
    }


    public async void RecordToDb(SiteResponse response)
    {
        var newRecord = new UptimeModel
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now,
            Status = response.Status,
            ResponseTime = (int)response.ResponseTime,
            Websiteid = response.Websiteid,
            Name = response.Name,
   
        };
        _logger.LogInformation(
                            $"Trying to Save {response.Name}");
        await _db.InsertUptime(newRecord);
    }

    
}
```

Comment: What does `websites` contain? Might some elements be `null`? It will cause that `website.Url` is throwing a ReferenceNullException.

Comment: It contains a Website model with Name, Websiteid, Url. The logger right above CheckSite(website.Name, website.Websiteid, website.Url) prints the info to the console so I know its grabbing all three from the database. It will also save the Name to the Database but nothing else, though thats all because the Url is emtpy from the iinitial method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `result.Url` is empty here:

```
_logger.LogInformation($"TEST URL: {result.Url}");
```

that's because it's a new instance of `SiteResponse()` method.

If it is showing as `null`, you'll need to create constructors on the class. Here is an example:

```
public class SiteResponse
{
    public SiteResponse(){  }
    public SiteResponse(string url){
        Url = url;
    }
    public int Websiteid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
    public long ResponseTime { get; set; }
}
```

and then initialize the new one like:

```
var result = new SiteResponse(Url);
```

Based on the comments below, I would refactor to something like this.

```
public class UptimeService
{
    private readonly ILogger<UptimeService> _logger;
    private readonly IWebsiteData _webdb;
    private readonly IUptimeData _db;
    public UptimeService(IWebsiteData webdb, IUptimeData db ,ILogger<UptimeService> logger) 
    {

        _webdb = webdb;
        _logger = logger;
        _db= db;
    }

    public class SiteResponse
    {
        public int Websiteid { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public bool Status { get; set; }
        public long ResponseTime { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task GetAllWebsites()
    {
       
        var websites = await _webdb.GetWebsites();

        foreach (var website in websites)
        {
         
            _logger.LogInformation($"WEBSITE::::: {website.Url} | {website.Name} | {website.Websiteid}");
            await CheckSite(website);
        }
        return ;
         
    }

    public async Task CheckSite(SiteResponse siteResponse)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        var client = new HttpClient();
        _logger.LogInformation(
                            $"TEST URL: {siteResponse.Url}");
        try
        {
            var checkingResponse = await client.GetAsync(siteResponse.Url);
            
            siteResponse.Status = checkingResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode &&
                            checkingResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        catch
        {
            siteResponse.Status = false;
            // offline
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        var elapsed = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        siteResponse.ResponseTime = elapsed;

    
        if (siteResponse.Status)
        {
            // archive record
            RecordToDb(siteResponse);
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                             $"Status is {siteResponse.Status}");
        }
        return;
    }


    public async void RecordToDb(SiteResponse response)
    {
        var newRecord = new UptimeModel
        {
            Time = DateTime.Now,
            Status = response.Status,
            ResponseTime = (int)response.ResponseTime,
            Websiteid = response.Websiteid,
            Name = response.Name,
   
        };
        _logger.LogInformation(
                            $"Trying to Save {response.Name}");
        await _db.InsertUptime(newRecord);
    }    
}
```

Comment: It also might be worth changing `CheckSite` to be an async method.  `async Task<SiteResponse> CheckSite`. Then you can do `await client.GetAsync(Url)`. I always find this to be a little cleaner over .Result.

Comment: Thanks! Ill give this a shot. That makes total sense. Would it make more sense to have this as a single method and not split up?

Comment: Was able to get this to work. Had to add the Name and Website ID, but now everything is functional! Thanks so much! Been hacking at this one for hours and just couldnt figure out where I was going wrong.

Comment: @Rahbit - I added an example above what you could potentially refactor to. You can return null and just pass in `SiteResponse`. You parent method will still be able to access the result in the object.

Comment: This looks pretty clean let me work on another revision now that its working correctly and I know had an output